# how to retrieve count from mysql between 2 hours

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `trans` (
  `transid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `affid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `transid` (`transid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and PHP code:

```
case "today":
    $sale=[];
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 23 ; $i++) {
        $hours[]= $i;
        $clicks[$i]=$api["clicks"][$i];
    }    
    break;
```

I want to add into the `$sale` array today's count of sales for each hour. Something like: $hours[5] = select count(*) from trans where .. date is between today's 04:59:59 - 06:00:00.

Comment: Do you want an hourly breakdown of the sales for the current day? Which field represents sales? I don't understand your PHP code as it has not relation to a database at all.

Comment: timestamp should not be `varchar`

Comment: timestamp should be stored as like?

Comment: @İkizKulelereDalanTeyyare Timestamp data should be stored in timestamp or datetime field (which have same format but slightly different behavior. There a few cases where it is a good idea to use a unix timestamp for storing times in the DB. And even then you would want to you a INT(10) field not an varchar(255).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$from=strtotime("".date("Y-m-d")." 04:59:59");
$to=strtotime("".date("Y-m-d")." 06:00:00");
?>

"SELECT * FROM `your_table` 
WHERE `date` > '".$from."' 
AND `date` < '".$to."'"
```

maybe?

You can use `gmdate()` if you need the current UTC time instead of the local time which you get with `date()`.

Comment: You need to quote the times

Comment: I have edited the answer now. Is this now more helpful? Try it and let me know. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are trying to use unix timestamps for your `timestamp` field, stop it now.  You are already making your life painful.  Use a MySQL timestamp field. There are honestly very few use cases where it is a good idea to use a unix timestamp field.

If you had a timestamp field you could do something like

```
SELECT HOUR(`timestamp`) AS `hour`, SUM(`transid`) AS `transaction_count`
FROM trans
WHERE `timestamp` LIKE CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),'%')
GROUP BY `hour`
ORDER BY `hour` ASC
```

That would give you the sales count for every hour of the current day. Make sure you add an index on `timestamp` for optimal query performance.

If you don't have a `timestamp`, then you need to utilize extra `FROM_UNIXTIME()` conversions, which would prevent you from being able to use an index on `timestamp`